# Future returns list before being populated

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database, async-await, future

I have the following method:

```
Future<List<Job>> getUserJobs() async {
    Query query = _firebaseDatabase
        .reference()
        .child("jobs")
        .child(_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)
        .orderByKey();

    List<Job> userJobs = [];
    if (query == null) {
      return userJobs;
    }

    query.onValue.listen((event) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = event.snapshot.value;
      values.forEach((key, value) {
        userJobs.add(Job.fromJson(key, Map.from(value)));
      });
    });
    return userJobs;
  }
```

I want to get this response in another class, however, the list returned by the above method is always []. I checked and the userJobs list is indeed populated but the return statement is executed before.

The structure of the database is:
Job collection has user IDs and for each user ID I have several job keys (each with its job data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Future<List<Job>> getUserJobs() async {

  List<Job> userJobs = [];
//  Query query = 
  await _firebaseDatabase
      .reference()
      .child("jobs")
      .child(_firebaseAuth.currentUser.uid)
  .once()
      .orderByKey().then((result) async {
        if (result.value != null) {
          result.value.forEach((key, childSnapshot) {
            userJobs.add(Job.fromJson(key, Map.from(childSnapshot)));
          });
        } else {
        print(
            'getUserJobs() no jobs found');
        }
  }).catchError((e) {
      print(
          'getUserJobs() error: $e');
  });

  
//  if (query == null) {
//    return userJobs;
//  }

//  query.onValue.listen((event) {
//    Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = event.snapshot.value;
//    values.forEach((key, value) {
//      userJobs.add(Job.fromJson(key, Map.from(value)));
//    });
//  });
  return userJobs;
}
```

your loop also needs to be async..otherwise the method will return before the loop finishes, returning the empty List.. been there and got quite frustrated by this..
also always use  `.catchError` callback.. it tells you what's going wrong ;)

Comment: It does indeed work! The only one thing that needed change was that .orderByKey() should be before .once() otherwise you get an error. Cheers!

Comment: Sure `.once()` is the query type so it goes last.. didn't noticed it wasn't while editing your code.. Glad I could help. As I said if you go web things get a bit complicated as official packages for all firebase services aren't yet available.. let me know if you need help with that too..Cheers